# Use OpenMP in the multithreading. Because of ignoring OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS

Tags: gcc, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, torch, openblas

While installing torch as follow :

```
git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
cd ~/torch; bash install-deps;
```

At this step :

```
   bash install-deps
```

The installation finished correctly. However l got a message that l don't understand.

```
  OS               ... Linux             
  Architecture     ... x86_64               
  BINARY           ... 64bit                 
  C compiler       ... GCC  (command line : gcc)
  Fortran compiler ... GFORTRAN  (command line : gfortran)
  Library Name     ... libopenblas_haswellp-r0.2.20.dev.a (Multi threaded; Max num-threads is 8)

 Use OpenMP in the multithreading. Because of ignoring OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS and GOTO_NUM_THREADS flags, 
 you should use OMP_NUM_THREADS environment variable to control the number of threads.



To install the library, you can run "make PREFIX=/path/to/your/installation install".

make -j 8 -f Makefile.install install
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/OpenBLAS'
Generating openblas_config.h in /opt/OpenBLAS/include
Generating f77blas.h in /opt/OpenBLAS/include
Generating cblas.h in /opt/OpenBLAS/include
Copying LAPACKE header files to /opt/OpenBLAS/include
Copying the static library to /opt/OpenBLAS/lib
Copying the shared library to /opt/OpenBLAS/lib
Generating openblas.pc in /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/pkgconfig
Generating OpenBLASConfig.cmake in /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/cmake/openblas
Generating OpenBLASConfigVersion.cmake in /opt/OpenBLAS/lib/cmake/openblas
Install OK!
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/OpenBLAS'
==> Torch7's dependencies have been installed
```

l don't understand this line :

```
To install the library, you can run "make PREFIX=/path/to/your/installation install".
```

What is the library to install and how ?

Before running :

```
./install.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is the output form the instalation of OpenBLAS which I supose is a dependency of torch.

That statemant says that you can change the default installation path of OpenBLAS but in the next line: 
    make -j 8 -f Makefile.install install
It is installing the library, and you can see the installation output after it.

So you dont need to do anithing.